# Enable your RDS or Admin password

Tags: coldfusion

I'm not sure why I'm getting this.  If I browse to

http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/JSON/Upload/Upload.cfc?method=Save&Item=1

Then the component works correctly.
But if I do this, then it asks for the RDS password.

```
!function($, window, undefined) {
    var local = {};
    local.data = {};
    local.type= 'post',
        local.dataType= 'json',
        local.data.method = 'Save';
    local.data = {
        Item : 'Item One'
    }

    var myPromise = $.ajax('Upload.cfc',local);
    myPromise.done(function(result) {
        console.log('success!');
    });

    myPromise.fail(function(A,B,C) {
        $('body').append(A.responseText);
        console.log(B);
        console.log(C);
    });
}(jQuery, window);
```

Finally, here's my component:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="Save" access="remote" output="yes">
    <cfargument name="Item">
    <cfset var local = {}>

    <cfquery datasource="#Application.Datasource#" username="#Application.Username#" password="#Application.Password#">
    INSERT INTO lru.Clip(ClipDesc) VALUES('test')
    </cfquery>
    #arguments.Item#
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phil,

I'm guessing that somehow your ajax code is calling the CFC without the "method" url param. When it does this CF thinks you are going to try the "CFC Explorer" - a neat little tool that creates a Javadoc like description of your CFC. You can see it (even on local) if you simply browse to your CFC without any url params as in:

http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/JSON/Upload/Upload.cfc

So something has to change with your Ajax call... I think that the issue is your last set statement...

```
local.data = {
    Item : 'Item One'
}
```

is replacing the "data" sets above it..... with a single struct called "Item". you are losing the key called "method" when you do it this way.  Try:

```
local.data.Item = 'Item One';
```

Comment: Phil - I wrote the first part without looking to see who was asking the question. I assume you probably already know about the "cfc explorer" - sorry for condescending :)

Comment: No problem at all Mark!  Oh!  Of course it's because I've overwritten data.method!  Bad Dobby!